# Finding maximum difference b/w index in an array, with constraint a[i]<=a[j] where i<j

Tags: algorithm

Here is my code, showing the wrong answer on a few test cases, can anyone tell me where it's failing.
I am not able to figure it out even after multiple attempts.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    //code
    int t,n;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin >> n;
        long long int a[n],max=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            cin >> a[i];
        int i=0,j=n-1;
        while(i<=j)
        {
            if(a[j]>=a[i]){
                max=j-i; break;}
            else if(a[j-1]>=a[i] || a[j]>=a[i+1])
               { max=j-i-1; break;}
            else
                i++;
                j--;
        }
        cout << max<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have to post also the problem description, and possibly some input/output examples

Comment: @Berto99 problem description is there in the question title itself

Answer (score 0):

One known case where the algorithm fails:

```
1 
5
5 7 6 2 3
```

The output, in this case, is 0, but it should be 2.

If the first two if conditions are not satisfied then you are incrementing `i`, here you are only comparing `i` with `j` and `j-1`, but there can be some other value of `k`  such that `k < j-1` and `(i,j)` is the answer.

Comment: Glad that it helped!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution in O(n log n):

1. Create a vector of index = 0 1 2 ... n-1
2. Sort (in a *stable* way) the indices `i, j`  such that `a[i] < a[i]`
3. Determine the max_index values

   `max_index[i]= max (index[j], j >= i)`

This can be calculated in a recursive way O(n)

4. For each index[i], determine `index_max[i+1] - ind[i]);` and determine the max of them

The maximum we obtained is the value we are looking for.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>

int diff_max (const std::vector<long long int> &a) {
    int n = a.size();
    std::vector<int> index(n), index_max(n);
    int dmax = 0;
    std::iota (index.begin(), index.end(), 0);
    std::stable_sort (index.begin(), index.end(), [&a] (int i, int j) {return a[i] < a[j];});
    index_max[n-1] = index[n-1];
    for (int i = n-2; i >= 0; --i) {
        index_max[i] = std::max (index_max[i+1], index[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i) {
        dmax = std::max (dmax, index_max[i+1] - index[i]);
    }
    return dmax;
}
    

int main() {
    int t, n;
    std::cin >> t;
    while(t--) {
        std::cin >> n;
        std::vector<long long int> a(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            std::cin >> a[i];
        
        auto max = diff_max (a);
        std::cout << max << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```